# Why isn't this perl script to save a youtube video, using wget, working correctly?

Tags: perl, bash, ubuntu, wget

The first argument should be the url of the video.  Can anyone point out to me why this isn't working?

I launched one of these ec2 instances of ubuntu 12.04 which has perl and wget installed already
http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/precise/current/

**This script originates from here:**
https://calomel.org/youtube_wget.html

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

## collect the URL from the command line argument
my $url = $ARGV[0] or die "\nError: You need to specify a YouTube URL\n\n";

## declare the user defined file name prefix 
my $prefix = defined($ARGV[1]) ? $ARGV[1] : "";

## download the html code from the youtube page
my $html = `wget -Ncq -e "convert-links=off" --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies /dev/null --no-check-certificate "$url" -O-`  or die  "\nThere was a problem downloading the HTML file.\n\n";

## collect the title of the page to use as the file name
my ($title) = $html =~ m/<title>(.+)<\/title>/si;
$title =~ s/[^\w\d]+/_/g;
$title =~ s/_Youtube_//ig;
$title =~ s/^_//ig;
$title = lc ($title);

## collect the URL of the video and translate to the proper URL
my ($download) = $html =~ /url_encoded_fmt_stream_map([\s\S]+?)fallback_host/ig;
$download =~ s/\\u0026/\&/g;
$download =~ s/^\=url%3D//g;
$download =~ s/%25/%/g;
$download =~ s/%3A/:/g;
$download =~ s/%2F/\//g;
$download =~ s/%3F/\?/g;
$download =~ s/%3D/\=/g;
$download =~ s/%252C/%2C/g;
$download =~ s/%26/\?/g;
$download =~ s/%253A/\:/g;

## print the file name of the video
print "\n     Download:   $prefix$title.webm\n\n";

## Download the file.
  my $error_code=system("wget -Ncq -e \"convert-links=off\" --load-cookies /dev/null --tries=50 --timeout=45 --no-check-certificate $download -O $prefix$title.webm &")>>8;
```

**EDIT**
After I run the perl script, the video doesn't download (it has a size of 0 bytes)

```
$ ./youtube_get_videos.pl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejkm5uGoxs4

     Download:   radscorpion_youtube.webm

$ ls -lh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Sep 14 04:40 radscorpion_youtube.webm
```

Comment: what? what does the ec2 instance have to do with the script?  what does "isn't working" look like, what *does* happen?

Comment: I just mentioned the ec2 instance in case some one wanted to reproduce the situation.  Will add an edit right now for the messaging I get after I run the script.

Comment: btw do you work for microsoft, amazon and/or are you a nirvana fan?

Comment: Print out `$download`. It may not be a properly formed url that you are handing to wget.

Comment: Here is the value stored in `$download`, it goes like this `=itag=45?url=http://o-o---preferred---sjc07s15---v18---lscache2.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=B0Z7NC6hQFk?sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire?fexp=926401%2C904448%2C920917%2C922401%2C920704%2C912806%2C913419%2C913558%2C913556%2C919003%2C912706%2C900816?key=yt1?expire=1347619154?itag=45?ipbits=8?sver=3?ratebypass=yes?mt=1347598272?ip=50.18.231.57?mv=m?source=youtube?ms=au?cp=U0hTTFZMV19KTkNOM19ORkFCOmdteS1IOGRMMlRB?id=7a3926e6e1a8c6ce?type=video/webm%3B%2Bcodecs=%22vp8.0%2C%2Bvorbis%22?`

Comment: Did you test/display `$error_code`?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is the "donald-duck", ampersand, `&`, in your `system` command.  You are not waiting for the program to complete.  I have no idea how long this is likely to take, but it won't be instantaneuos.  The error-code of 0 that you (probably) get from `system` will be returned by the shell (`&` will invoke a shell), not the `wget`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me CPAN that for you: [WWW::YouTube::Download](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aYouTube%3a%3aDownload). After installing this module, simply use the bundled `youtube-download` utility:

```
stas@Stanislaws-MacBook-Pro:~$ youtube-download -o "{title}.{suffix}" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejkm5uGoxs4 
--> Working on ejkm5uGoxs4
Downloading `RADSCORPION!.mp4`
26320989/26320989 (100.00%)
Download successful!
stas@Stanislaws-MacBook-Pro:~$ file RADSCORPION\!.mp4 
RADSCORPION!.mp4: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2
stas@Stanislaws-MacBook-Pro:~$
```

Works like a charm :)